# Bootstrap4 modal is not working on mobile and tablet

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Modal is not working on mobile and tablet. I am using bootstrap4 modal in angular7.

Below is the code which i used to open a modal. Below code used in app.component.html to open a modal. Please help.

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-12 cancel-exit-block">

    <li><a href="#" onclick="void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openAllowModal">Modal</a></li>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="openAllowModal" role="dialog">
  <p>open modal</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why my code is not appearing in above question. Please check below code.  I had followed below link to fix the issue but still no luck.       https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event#Safari_Mobile       
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-12 cancel-exit-block">

    <li><a href="#" onclick="void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openAllowModal">Modal</a></li>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="openAllowModal" role="dialog">
  <p>open modal</p>
</div>

Comment: In order for the modals to work you need to include all JavaScrip files. Please refer to the Bootstrap docs

Comment: I had used javascript files also. Please refer below code.    
      
      <script>    
          $('#openAllowModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {    
          $('#openAllowModal').focus()    
          })    
      </script>    
         
      <script>    
             $(document).ready(function() {    
             $("#openAllowModal").modal();    
          });    
            </script>

Comment: @RBCunhaDesign I had used above javascript to open a modal but no luck.

Comment: The modal not working both android and ios devices and tablets.Please help on this.

Comment: Is it working on desktop?

Comment: Yes it’s working on desktop.

Comment: For now i moved angular material for modals.

Answer (score 1):

To open a bootstrap modal you always need a div with the class `modal-dialog` and a div with the class `modal-content`
You can give a look to some example here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

So try to transform your last div

```
<div class="modal fade" id="openAllowModal" role="dialog">
  <p>open modal</p>
</div>
```

to this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="openAllowModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p>open modal</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```